# Not able to see header in visualforce page (classic)?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting, third-party

I am unable to see header in classing though it working fine when i am switching to lightning .

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" showHeader="true" >
<script>
  window.onload=function()       
    {        

        window.location = "Example.com";
    };
</script>

<body >

</body>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not directly assign a value to window.onload, because Visualforce uses it to initialize the page. Instead, use window.addEventListener:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { /* do something here */ });
```

Comment: As per my requirement : I need to create visualforce tab and once user click on the tab it will open third party web application(Report on Public Server) .

Comment: @siddhar If you're using window.location, you're navigating away from Salesforce, too. Have you tried using a Web Tab instead?